# How to migrate from Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlyics (Firebase Project not in the list)

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

We have our app in Firebase and in Crashlytics.

Now we have to migrate Crashlytics (Fabric) to Firebase Crashlytics.

In my **Firebase** account I have around 40 Projects.

At the https://www.fabric.io/firebase_migration/apps Page.

I have in the section.

**"FABRIC APPS WITH MATCHING FIREBASE APPS"**

- 26 Android Apps

and in the section.

**"ALL OTHER FABRIC APPS"**

- I have 3 more Android Apps

On the right side of the page I find **23 Firebase Projects** but I have **40 Projects ** (some one are missing)

How to add the missing Firebase Project to fabric migration page ?

How to I link my Fabric Crashlytic App to my Firebase Project which is *not* at the migration page ?

How the Fabric Apps with Matching Firebase Apps work ?

Regards

Comment: Please contact Firebase support for questions like this.  Stack Overflow is not likely to be of much help.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 4):

The problem was :

Only project's where you are the *owner* are listed at the Fabric mirgration page

https://www.fabric.io/firebase_migration/